# laravel : How to run query for user input in sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have to make a report of some certain data where user will give two date range. so I have to show data in between that range.
how to run query for that user input date?

Here is my controller:

```
 public function reportByDate(Request $request){
       $now = $request->Input(['sdate']);
       $then=$request->Input(['edate']);
       $input = DB::select('SELECT sum(fee), courses.name FROM `fees`  JOIN
                    courses on fees.course_id=courses.id join
                    users on courses.id =users.course_id
                    where users.completed_status=1 AND users.date between 'now' AND 'then' group by fees.course_id');

   return view('revenueDetails','input'=>$input]);
    }
```

How to pass this two input data (now and then in that sQL Query?

Comment: are your query return you any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$input = DB::table('fees')->join('courses', 'fees.course_id', '=','courses.id')
            ->join('users', 'users.course_id', '=', 'courses.id')
            ->where('users.completed_status', 1)
            ->whereBetween('users.date', [$now, $then])
             ->groupBy('fees.course_id')
            ->selectRaw('SUM(fee), courses.name')
             ->get();
```

Comment: there is a problem with your query, groupBy I think, just check onece.if possible

Comment: you've tried? What's the error?. I've update it. it missing ''.

Comment: Fixed. My mistake.

Comment: Everything is ok.you may be forgot to put  '   '

 `->whereBetween('users.date', [$now, $then])`

Comment: Great! maybe my eyes too tired to see all this code. I've update the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use DB::raw with params

```
$input = DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT sum(fee), courses.name FROM `fees`  JOIN
                courses on fees.course_id=courses.id join
                users on courses.id =users.course_id
                where users.completed_status=1 AND users.date between
                :now AND :then group by fees.course_id',
                ["now" => $now, "then" => $then]));
```